# How do I fix [object Object] in rel=stylesheet in webpack output?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, css-loader, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader

When I tried to webpack my project, I'm getting this error `<link rel=stylesheet href=[object Object]>` my expected output for CSS styles  `./styles.css`. 
I'm new to webpack, Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Here are my files I'm working on:

**webpack.config.common.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
//const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    //    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    //      filename: 'index.html',
    //      inject: true,
    //      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
    //    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**Index.js File**

```js
import './index.css';
import styles from './css/bootstrap.min.css';
import customstyles from './scss/main.css';

import html from './index.html';
```

**webpack.config.prod.js**

```js
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const ImageminWebpWebpackPlugin = require('imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin');
const ImageminWebP = require('imagemin-webp');

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]', 'extract-loader', 'html-loader'],
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },

      // Image Compression
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65,
              },
              // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
              optipng: {
                enabled: false,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: [0.65, 0.9],
                speed: 4,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              // the webp option will enable WEBP
              webp: {
                quality: 75,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    //new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
    }),

    new ImageminWebpWebpackPlugin({
      plugins: [
        ImageminWebP({
          quality: 75,
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
        cssProcessorOptions: {
          map: {
            inline: false,
            annotation: true,
          },
        },
      }),
      new TerserPlugin({
        // Use multi-process parallel running to improve the build speed
        // Default number of concurrent runs: os.cpus().length - 1
        parallel: true,
        // Enable file caching
        cache: true,
        sourceMap: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
});
```

**List of plugins i have installed:**

```
"@babel/core": "^7.9.0",

"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",

"@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^2.1.0",

"babel-loader": "^8.1.0",

"clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",

"copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",

"css-loader": "^3.4.2",

"extract-loader": "^5.0.1",

"file-loader": "^6.0.0",

"html-loader": "^1.0.0",

"html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.3",

"image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",

"imagemin": "^7.0.1",

"imagemin-webp": "^5.1.0",

"imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.1",

"imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.2",

"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",

"node-sass": "^4.13.1",

"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",

"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",

"purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",

"sass-loader": "^8.0.2",

"style-loader": "^1.1.3",

"terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5",

"webpack": "^4.42.1",

"webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",

"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",

"webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
```

Thanks in advance
Krish

Comment: What generates  your html?